# Adding data to a Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've just started playing around with python lists, I've written the simple code below expecting the printed file to display the numbers [12,14,16,18,20,22] but only 22 is displayed. Any help would be great.

```
a=10
b=14
while a <= 20:
    a=a+2
    b=b-1
    datapoints=[]
    datapoints.insert(0,a)
print datapoints
```

Comment: Well, you are setting `datapoints` to an empty list *in the loop*. I suggest you move the `datapoints=[]` line to take place *outside* of the loop.

Comment: Also, use `list.append()` if you expected numbers to be added at the end, which your expected output suggests you want.

Comment: Does `b` have a purpose?

Comment: Or if you want to prepend the numbers, use `collections.deque` so you can call `appendleft` and perform the prepend efficiently (`list`s only have efficient appends on the right, prepending is `O(n)`).

Comment: `while` is often not that pythonic IMO for a case like this, consider using a `for` loop instead in combination with `range`

Answer (score 1):

```
a=10
b=14
datapoints=[]  # this needs to be established outside of your loop

while a <= 20:
    a=a+2
    b=b-1
    datapoints.append(a)
print datapoints
```

You need to set up datapoints outside your loop, and then inside your loop, append each additional datum to datapoints

Comment: cheers, I'm new to this and sometimes its hard to see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

Joel already answered but if you want a more compact code you can use range

```
numbers = []
for number in range(12,24,2):
    # do whatever you want with b
    numbers.append(number)

print numbers
```

or if you only want to print the numbers you can do

```
print [number for number in range(12,24,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the expected list as output by using the [range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) method. It takes three parameters, start, stop and step.

```
data_points = range(12, 23, 2)  # range returns list in python 2
print data_points
```

Note that, in `python 3` the [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is a [sequence-type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). So, you will have to cast it to `list` in python 3

```
data_points = list(range(12, 23, 2))  # python 3
print(data_points)
```